# PHP: Using an SSH class inside a different class constructor

Tags: php, ssh, constructor

I am still rather green when it comes to PHP.  Not quite sure where the issue comes in here.  I am using a rather simple SSH2 class (https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/34450.html) that works well for my needs, or has until this point.

This is the class I have set up.  I put the ssh connection into the constructor, and attempt to use $this->ssh throughout the rest of the class functions.

```
include ("/var/www/html/class/ssh2_class.php"); ##https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/34450.html

class crontab {

   function __construct($host,$params) {
      $this->host = $host;
      $this->pubkey  =  $params['pubkey'];
      $this->privkey =  $params['privkey'];
      $this->usr     =  $params['user'];
      $this->port    =  $params['port'];
      $this->secret  =  $params['secret'];

      $this->ssh = new SSH2($this->host)
         or die ("Unable to connect to ". $this->host ."!");
      $this->ssh->auth($this->usr, $this->pubkey, $this->privkey, $this->secret)
         or die ("Unable to authenticate to ". $this->host ."!");
   }

   function show($sudo) {
      if ($sudo) { $sudo = "sudo"; } else { $sudo = ""; }
      $cmd = $sudo."$sudo crontab -l";
      $this->ssh->exec($cmd);
      return ($this->ssh->output);
   }
```

The issue I run into is in the **return** line of the **show** function above.  The **$this->ssh->exec($cmd);** works without issue; I've tested it by simply touching a file.

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: SSH2::$output in /home/mackay_c/scripts/deploy/deploy.class.php on line 26
```

I've searched around the web, and am at a bit of a loss as to why this occurs.  The 'output' function in the SSH2 class is:

```
 function output() {
    return stream_get_contents($this->stream);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the class source from the URL in the `include()` comment, it's a method that needs `()` as `$this->ssh->output()` not a property `$this->ssh->output`

Comment: *facepalm*  Have you ever had one of those days?  Thanks.  Such a simple thing and I stared at for so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 return ($this->ssh->output())
```

Comment: Answers are more useful when you provide some supporting information.

Comment: Agreed, seemed simple enough though.

Comment: The sad fact is that I even stated the line above it works, and of course has the parenthesis...  it was just a *facepalm* moment.